# AngularDart CustomEvent listener from JS Event

Tags: javascript, dart, angular-dart, dom-events, dart-html

I'm attempting to port a working JavaScript event listener to AngularDart.

In AngularDart I confirmed (via alert "ready!") that the initial 'app-ready' document event listener is invoked, but receive no follow-on event messages. What am I missing that would allow AngularDart to receive the follow-on event messages like the JavaScript code does?

Below is a working JavaScript event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('app-ready', function() {
    app.listen(function(message) {
        switch (message.name) {
            case "name1":
                alert(message.payload.message);
                break;
            case "name2":
                alert(message.payload.message);
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Below is my attempt at porting the above JavaScript into my AngularDart:

```
import 'dart:js';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() async {
        document.on["app-ready"].listen((CustomEvent message) {
            context.callMethod('alert', ['ready!']);
            app.listen(_eventReady(message));
        });
    }
    Future _eventReady(CustomEvent message) async {
        var messageEvent = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(message);
        if (messageEvent['name'] == "name1") {
            context.callMethod('alert', [messageEvent['payload']['message']]);
        }
        if (messageEvent['name'] == "name2") {
            context.callMethod('alert', [messageEvent['payload']['message']]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use `dart:html` for the first part:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  document.on['app-ready'].listen((event) {
    // ...
  });
}
```

I'll need more context to help you with the second.

Comment: Thanks matanlurey. Yes, I'm using 'html'. I can catch and display the message in the included JavaScript but am unable to do the same in dart.

The event sent from the backend is in the form: {"name":"window.cmd.message","targetID":"1","message":{"name":"name1","payload":{"message":"message1"}}}

Comment: Maybe a timing problem?